# Scipy minimize a scalar with Brent method throws an Overflow 34

Tags: python, scipy

I'd like to find a local minimum of the function `f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x - 2`
where `x` is between `<-10; 10>`. I use Anaconda 3 on Windows 64bit.

My scipy python code throws an error:

```
from scipy import optimize
def f(x):
    return (x**3)+(x**2)+x-2
x_min = optimize.minimize_scalar(f, bounds=[-10, 10], method='brent')
```

> OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Isn't a power to 3 too simple function to break a scipy optimization package?

Comment: According to the documentation of `minimize_scalar`, if you want to restrict the solution within `bounds`, you should use `method = 'bounded'`. Apparently, the `brent` method does not respect the bounds and breaks since your function is unbounded

Comment: that's it, you can write it as a solution @Stelios , I'll accept it

Comment: I'd appreciate a hint why Brent cannot be applied here, I couldn't find an answer why ```x^2``` works with Brent, while the power to 3 won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using local boundaries, changing `method` to `'bounded'` is required

```
from scipy import optimize
def f(x):
    return (x**3)+(x**2)+x-2
x_min = optimize.minimize_scalar(f, bounds=[-10, 10], method='bounded')
print(x_min)
```